# Issues with UIActivityIndicator not showing up

Tags: ios, uiwebview, indicator

I am trying to make my application open a musicfile on dropbox thru UIWebView. I have made the music play only on click with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender {

    NSString *stream = @"...";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Webview loadRequest:urlrequest];
    [Webview addSubview: activityIndicator];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I want to add an indicator to show up after the button is clicked till the quicktime player appears so to notify the user that the button has actually been clicked. I have done this with the following code:

```
-(void)loading {
     if (!Webview.loading)
         [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

     else
         [activityIndicator startAnimating];

 }
```

However, i have a problem: the uiviewindicator disappears one the button has been clicked! Could someone help me and point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is difficult to answer given the limited amount of info.  Are you using a XIB or storyboard?  It looks like you're creating it elsewhere and are adding it to the view.  My guess is that your webview is obscuring the activity indicator.  You probably want to bring the activity indicator to the front, eg: [self bringSubviewToFront: activityIndicator];

Comment: @NicholasHart I am using .xib but the activity indicator is not behind the webview because the webview is so small, it is not shown in the window. Thank you for your help anyways! :) Abdullah Shafique solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your play method take out:

```
[Webview addSubview: activityIndicator];
```

Comment: @DCB By the way if you think the answer is good you could give me a plus 1.